# Insert a value for key into NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I think this could be a very easy question for you.

But I have searched a lot and I don't know if I am very fool or I am using the wrong class (`NSMutableArray`).

I want to add an object for a specific key so that I can retrieve it later.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray *grisOcurrencias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[grisOcurrencias setValue:ocurrencia forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", pixelVal]];
```

But the array is not getting inserted in the array, if I do something like:

```
[grisOcurrencias addObject: ocurrencia]
```

The object is inserted.

Am I doing something wrong?

Other thing... I want to recover the object by its key, what method should I use?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `NSMutableDictionary`, not `NSMutableArray`. Dictionaries store objects based on a key, whereas arrays store objects based on an index.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dict setObject:something forKey:@"Some Key"];

// ... and later ...

id something = [dict objectForKey:@"Some Key"];
```

Comment: You are GOD ! Thanks I was getting confused, because a saw a Object with some methods whith the "Key" word like SetValue forKey, well, thanks friend :D

Answer (score 4):

You want to use an `NSDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *grisOcurrencias = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[grisOcurrencias setObject:ocurrencia forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", pixelVal]];
```

And then to retrieve the object:

```
id object = [grisOcurrencias objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", pixelVal]];
```

And array is an ordered collection of items, where each item has an integer index. A dictionary is a collection of objects, each of which is set and retrieved according to a key, just like a real dictionary, with the keys being words and the values (objects) being definitions.